# Spark Graphx inDegrees Sorting - sortBy Vs sortWith

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am trying to sort the vertex list based on in-degrees in a Spark Graph (using Scala)

```
// Sort Ascending - both the 2 below yeild same results

gGraph.inDegrees.collect.sortBy(_._2).take(10)

gGraph.inDegrees.collect.sortWith(_._2 < _._2).take(10)

// Sort Decending 

gGraph.inDegrees.collect.sortWith(_._2 > _._2).take(10)

gGraph.inDegrees.collect.sortBy(_._2, ascending=false).take(10)     //Doesnt Work!!
```

I expect the results of `sortBy(_._2, ascending=false)` to be same as the `sortWith(_._2>_._2)` as mentioned above. But getting the below error. Appreciate any thoughts around this. Thanks!

> scala> gGraph.inDegrees.collect.sortBy(_.*2, ascending=false).take(10)
>   :55: error: too many arguments for method sortBy: (f:
>   ((org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int)) => B)(implicit ord:
>   scala.math.Ordering[B])Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int)]
>                 gGraph.inDegrees.collect.sortBy(*._2, ascending=false).take(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing `.collect` first, you are calling `.sortBy` on an `Array`, not on an `RDD`. `Array`'s `sortBy` method takes only one parameter (you can't specify `ascending`).

You should usually let spark handle as much of the computation as possible, and only `collect` (or `take`) at the very end. Try this:

```
gGraph.inDegrees.sortBy(_._2, ascending=false).take(10)
```

Comment: yes, it works. thanks!  scala> gGraph.inDegrees.sortBy(_._2, ascending=false).take(10)
res122: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int)] = Array((10397,152), (13930,145), (11298,143), (11292,132), (12266,107), (13487,96), (12892,82), (11618,82), (11433,81), (14869,80))